# How to check which files are not set to "Standard" storage class on amazon S3 bucket

Tags: class, amazon-s3, storage, bucket

When using Amazon AWS service S3, is there an easy way to check if ALL files in a bucket has its storage class set to "Standard"?

If any files is set to either "Standard - Infrequent Access" or "Reduced Redundancy" i would like a list with all those files, so i can change their storage class to "Standard".

--------EDIT---------

I have created an AWS CLI command, that can do the above. It is as follows:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucketName --query 'Contents[?StorageClass != `STANDARD`][].{Key:Key}'
```

(STANDARD should be surrounded with ` but they dont show for some reason.)

But it made me think about, what this kind of request will cost on a very large bucket with millions of files. If the line above returns 5 files, would i then be charged for 5 requests, or would i be charged for every single file that is accessed in the search?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the new ["inventory" service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) on S3. If you go to the AWS webconsole and browse to the S3 bucket management page (you need to use the new style console if it asks). Here you can select Inventory and configure you're export. You can select the storage class here easily.

NB: the bucket you're exporting NEEDS to have the correct permissions to receive inventory exports. You can find an example of the bucket policy in the [S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-9).

Comment: Iam able to change the storage class for all my files, but what i want to do is to make a script that can show me a list of all files that is not set to "Standard". Fx to check if someone has added a new file with the storage class set to eg. "Reduced Redundancy" by mistake. Perhabs though AWS CLI?

Comment: You can use AWS CLI, but that will be quite expensive depending on the amount of objects in your bucket. If you can wait 24-48 hours it MUCH cheaper (factor 1000) to retrieve the list using bucket inventories.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked fine for me.

`` aws s3api list-objects --bucket XXXX --query 'Contents[?StorageClass
!= `STANDARD`].[Key,StorageClass]' --output text > XXXX.txt ``

Answer (score 0):

> But it made me think about, what this kind of request will cost on a very large bucket with millions of files. If the line above returns 5 files, would i then be charged for 5 requests, or would i be charged for every single file that is accessed in the search?

This is filtered at the client.  You will be charged for each ListObjects request, which returns 1000 objects with each call by default under `aws s3api list-objects`.  The cost in the least expensive regions, such as us-east-1 and us-east-2, is $0.005 per 1,000 LIST requests. (Not per object, per request.)  Since each request returns 1,000 objects, the cost for iterating through 2,000,000 objects is about $0.01, which seems pretty reasonable.  Some other regions are a little bit higher.

Running inside EC2 in the same region as the bucket, you won't pay any associated data transport charges, and you will have the best performance due to very low latency.  Bemchmarks I've recently done suggest you could should be able to scan a million objects in under 10 minutes.  It's relatively fast because you only have to iterate the listing, because storage class is one of the attributes returned in object listings.

Use reasonable caution if switching objects from `STANDARD_IA`, because if an object is moved out of `STANDARD_IA` before it has been in that class for at least 30 days, you'll still be charged for the 30 day mimumum storage charge that applies to all objects in that class.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Ty for the clarification.